# Can't correctly import six module via pip when I was installing easy install

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

it has already claimed that I have either installed or upgraded six module

```
C:\Users\floatSD\Downloads\setuptools-34.3.1\setuptools-34.3.1>pip install --upgrade six

Requirement already up-to-date: six in c:\users\floatsd\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

but it shows error run the `easy_install.py`

```
C:\Users\floatSD\Downloads\setuptools-34.3.1\setuptools-34.3.1>python easy_install.py
```

and it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "easy_install.py", line 4, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.easy_install import main
  File "C:\Users\floatSD\Downloads\setuptools-34.3.1\setuptools-34.3.1\setuptools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from six.moves import filter, map
ImportError: No module named six.moves
```

p.s. my pip version is 9.0.1

I tried uninstall and install six again, but still doesn't work

```
C:\Users\floatSD\Downloads\setuptools-34.3.1\setuptools-34.3.1>pip uninstall six
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling six-1.10.0:
  c:\users\floatsd\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six-1.10.0-py3.5.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled six-1.10.0

C:\Users\floatSD\Downloads\setuptools-34.3.1\setuptools-34.3.1>pip install six
Collecting six
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six
Successfully installed six-1.10.0

C:\Users\floatSD\Downloads\setuptools-34.3.1\setuptools-34.3.1>python easy_install.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "easy_install.py", line 4, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.easy_install import main
  File "C:\Users\floatSD\Downloads\setuptools-34.3.1\setuptools-34.3.1\setuptools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from six.moves import filter, map
ImportError: No module named six.moves
```

Comment: try reinstalling it. `pip uninstall six` and then `pip install six`